# How to read a comma separated `csv` file into pandas dataframe if it contains a comma separated elements in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have the following `test2.csv` file:

```
id,name,city,country
1,David, Johnson,London,UK,
2,Mary, Gueta,NY,USA,
3,Matthias, Nile,Munich,Germany,
```

I want to read it into a pandas dataframe. Using this code

```
df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')
```

I get the following df:

[image]

But I want to store the first name and last name together in the column `name`. `id` column should store the numbers. `city` and `country` should also store the appropriate values.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
file = open(`temp.csv')
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
header = []
header = next(csvreader)
new_rows = []
for row in csvreader:
    new_rows.append([row[0], row[1]+','+row[2], row[3], row[4]])
file.close()
df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns =header )
df
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Now the column `city` stores the values `Johnson`, `Gueta`, and `Nile`

Comment: Interesting. When I run this code with the given input, `city` column contains the correct values (London, NY, and Munich)

Comment: @dilara I was talking about the first edit.

Answer (score 1):

step1: combined with 'id' & 'name' columns named a new column 'full_name'

```
df['full_name'] = df['id'].map(str) + '.' + df['name'].map(str)
```

step2: sorted the 'id' column

```
df.loc[:,'id'] = list(range(df.shape[0]))
```

step3: delete 'name' column

```
del df['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful pattern to distinguish between values, space appears after comma in names, so you can substitute delimiter "," with "|" that is more efficient to avoid this type of confusion

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import re


#substitute comma not followed by space for vertical bar in the original file and save it as a new file
with open('test2.csv', 'r') as infile, open('test2_vb.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = re.sub(',(?! )', '|', line)
        outfile.write(line)

file = open('test2_vb.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file , delimiter='|')
#load the data into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(reader)
print(df)
```

this way using a regular expression the file can be corrected (though at the end of a line should not be separator)

Answer (score 0):

You can change `1,David, Johnson,London,UK` to `1,"David, Johnson",London,UK` then load it using `pd.DataFrame`.

This happens because pandas think it is another value and to avoid that you need use quotations.

If you have line breaks in your value you will also need to use quotations.

you can find basic rules of csv from [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).